# Auto_raise broken in GNOME 3.4.1?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, mutter

Since dist-upgrading 12.04 LTS in such a manner as resulted in an upgrade of GNOME from 3.2.x to 3.4.1, auto_raise is broken.

I have the usual auto_raise* settings set in gconf, in apps -> metacity -> general.  But 
the functionality just doesn't work anymore.

Focus follows mouse works fine, yes, but windows just no longer raise after a short delay.  I have tried both gconf and tweak tool-based remedies, to no avail.

Any ideas on how to work around this?  Auto-raise is a really integral part of my workflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is because gconf-editor is being phase out in favor of dconf-editor. I had a similar problem (actually the opposite, I was trying to disable auto_raise and it wouldn't work). It seems that the setting in gconf-editor is overwritten by the setting in dconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
```

Navigate to `org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences`.