# How can one prevent new windows from taking focus in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, window, focus

I want to prevent new windows from acquiring focus. A way to do this is provided in Ubuntu 10.10 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8494/prevent-windows-from-stealing-focus) and in Ubuntu 12.04 [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/158174/204323). How can something similar be achieved in Ubuntu 14.04? The auto-raise setting in Ubuntu Tweak Tool's additional workspace settings looks promising, but I have no idea how to use it.