# What is the current method to prevent applications from taking focus?

Tags: window-manager

One thing that I can't stand in any operating system is apps that take and hold focus when you open them. For example, when I open Netbeans in Ubuntu 18.04, it has a small splash screen that opens right in the middle of my screen, and no matter what I do, I can't do anything to make any other window appear above it.

I never want any application to ever take focus when I open it, I'll turn to it when I'm ready. And I definitely don't want any application to be able to hold focus in such a way that it denies me the option of doing anything else while it displays a loading screen.

There's [this unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/q/505098/17041) on this site regarding the same problem, and [this thread on the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2239651) page which has answers involving Compiz and Unity and other out of date options.

I am using the Cinammon desktop on Ubuntu 18.04. Is there any setting I can use to deny any apps the ability to take and/or hold focus when opening?

Comment: I don't use Cinnamon, but Openbox or KWin would allow you to make global rules.

Comment: To be honest I haven't used cinnamon in years so I don't know if there's a built in function (on xfce there is though and on gnome it's the default behaviour), but I think that, as @DK Bose suggested, you're best bet is changing window manager.